# Reading values from a memory address in Ada

Tags: ada

I am trying to write a procedure that given a memory address and data type, will display the value of the data at that memory location.

I'm thinking that the best way to do this would be to use the To_Pointer function in the generic package Address_To_Access_Conversions, but every time I try to use it I get an error:

invalid prefix in selected component "Address_To_Access_Conversions"

I've ben unable to find any examples of how the Address_To_Access_Conversions is actually used. And I may be on the totally wrong track.

Does anyone know how to use the above package to convert an Address to an Access type and more importantly, a good way to access data at a given address to display to console?

---

### Edit

The solution I found most in my research was to use something like the following:

```
for X'Address use dummy_address;
```

The only problem was that at that point in the code, I hadn't calculated what the dummy address was and that statement would only work at declaration, before 'begin'  I found a way around this though with block programming:

```
dummy_address := base_address + offset;

Dummy_String:
declare
  subtype Xdummy is Integer;
  S : Xdummy;
  for S'Address use dummy_address;
begin
  --More code here
end Dummy_String;
```

Comment: post a simple complete code example that exhibits the error

Comment: From your question i think you may not have come across an [address clause](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Attributes/%27Address)

Comment: Did you _instantiate_ the generic package?  I'm thinking that trying to use a generic package directly, instead of instantiating it, might be a cause of an "invalid prefix" error.  `Address_To_Access_Conversions` is probably the best and cleanest way to accomplish this, but like Brian, I'd like to see your failing code and then we can help you get it right.

Comment: I was actually struggling with where to start, I'm still new to Ada.  I updated my post with the solution I found.  I would still like to learn how to use the Address_To_Access_Conversions package because it looks like it might be useful later so I'll look into how to instantiate it.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Solutions are to be posted as *answers* and **not** by editing the original question. You can self-answer your own question.